# Android : Parse obtainStyledAttributes CardView cardElevation

Tags: android

How does one parse the cardElevation xml attribute programmatically? I've tried the following to no avail:

```
int elevation = getDimension(context, attrs, new int[]{android.support.v7.cardview.R.styleable.CardView_cardElevation});   
int elevation = getDimension(context, attrs, new int[]{android.support.v7.cardview.R.attr.cardElevation});

private int getDimension(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int[] systemAttrs) {
   TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, systemAttrs);    
   int dimension = a.getDimension(0, 0);    
   a.recycle();     
   return dimension; // all return 0
}
```

**xml :**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ...
    app:cardElevation="2dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed this myself.

```
String elevation = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", "cardElevation");
```

Note that the elevation is returned as `String`, such as "4.0dip".

There is another way to do this

```
typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CardView);
float elevation = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.CardView_cardElevation, 0);
```

But, note that getDimension() method converts dp, sp values into pixel values.